# Counting how many times a member boosted a server discord.js

Tags: javascript, discord.js

I would like to have a premium system based on server boosts of the support server for my bot. I know that I can check if someone is a booster for example by checking for the server booster role, but is it possible to check how many times they have boosted the server?
Like, if they boost once, they get access to tier 1 things, if they boost twice they would get access to tier 2 etc.
I've seen some discussion about this topic on the discord support features request page, but it is like 2 years old and I couldn't find the result of that suggestion (accepted/denied).
If there is a way outside of discord.js, but via interacting with the discord api directly, that could also work.
Thanks in advance

Comment: I don't think so.  https://support.discord.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/360072098592-Allow-servers-to-track-boost-count-for-individual-users